# css input style not working on firefox mobile

Tags: html, css

Since applying `contenteditable` doesn't "work" on vuejs, I replaced the field that I wanted to allow users to edit with a `input` field to which I applied `border-style:none;`.

This is my html:

```html
<span v-if="modif_autorisee">
   <input class="input_text_nostyle" type="text" @input="envoititre" v-model="ligne.intitule" id="intitule_245">
</span>
```

and css:

```css
.input_text_nostyle{
    border-style:none;
    font-family:$font-stack;
    color: $text-color; 
    @include media("<small") {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        max-width: 9rem;
    }
}
```

It is working fine on the various navigators that I checked with, but not on firefox on Android, the input fields do have borders and their width is standard, no limited to `9rem`.

Comment: try outline: none; https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/outline